# react toolbox date picker left right arrow not working

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-toolbox

I am using react toolbox date picker component. I am getting issue with chevron-left and chevron right arrow in calendar. In place of the icon of arrows am getting values as chevron-left and chevron right. Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your date picker code?

Answer (score 3):

Icons are not included in react-toolbox.
Try adding the following line in your html:
`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: You can also refer to this guide by google: http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#getting-icons